# Marketing Cloud inbound SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, mobileconnect

Please help, I wanted to retrieve all of the inbound SMS in our Marketing Cloud. Kindly let me know how what are the best ways to do this (ampscript/report, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Example two ways:

1. Query the [SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) data view with `Inbound = 1`. Results will be limited to one business unit
2. In Reports create a "SMS Message Detail Report". This can extract all inbound text messages if run in the root business unit, but will not be limited to inbound SMS - you will need to filter the report.